# ExtJs tab panel random disappear

Tags: extjs, tabs, extjs4.1, tabpanel

I've an Ext.tab.Panel that contain in each tab some object (that are Ext.panel.Panel).
When I try to switch between tabs the items contained in the tab random disappear, like in the picture.

[image]

Is it a known issue or have I made a mistake?

Thank you

Marco

Comment: You have most likely made a mistake, probably with the layouts of the individual tabs.

Comment: Provide code for this.

Comment: Not sure without seeing the code but it is quite easy to mess up layouts in 4.1 with the Card layout(which tabpanel uses) because it has a global suspending of layouts.  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238658-4.1.*-setActiveItem-layout-issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for comments.

I was having twice problems reported from zeke ank pllee.

For all people are having the same problem be careful how to use layout. I've set layout fit inside each element, removing all "layout" value it works.

However I've already had also pllee reported problem, with the same problem of layout render. Last time I've solved forcing doLayout() of all component in active tab